# Why does Xcode's autocomplete always think my properties are int?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've been seeing this for well over a year and I can't figure out if it's a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

When I declare a property in one of my classes like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *aString;
```

And I go to use this somewhere else like

```
myObject.aStr[ESC]
```

When the list pops down with all the suggestions, aString is *always* of type int. All of my properties are like this.

I've tried this on different installations, on different machines, releases or betas.

Anyone else seeing this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'll just chime in that I see the same thing.  I just chalk it up to brokenness that doesn't cause a problem- all I need 99% of the time is for the editor to complete the rest accurately and save me the trouble of looking it up myself.  Come to think of it, the auto complete feature has always been wonky, so maybe I don't even notice it any more.  It gets confused very easily (ie, preprocessor macros are virtually guaranteed to muck it up, in my experience).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Xcode 3.1.x.  The version of Xcode in the Snow Leopard release has many fixes to autocompletion behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because that in some circumstances, undefined types in C are treated as `int` and Xcode doesn't have a background compiler (like Visual Studio does for C#) for its 'intellisense'.

If you compile your project right after declaring the property, Xcode should see the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps XCode is picking up on the fact that what you have is not a string, it's a pointer to a string. There is no reason why it *should* think that it's an int, but maybe the fact that pointer are 4 bytes and ints are also 4 bytes causes this to happen. Building probably fixes this problem. I'll update when I get back to my mac.

Comment: To follow up, I tried the use case in xcode, and had no problems.